# Multi-threading to count recurrences of characters in a file

Tags: python

I'm trying to use multi-threading in Python in order to go through a large file of text (characters) and count recurrences of the same characters.

How can I go about setting it up so that I can use the above to methods with multiple threads and process a file to count the recurrences of a character?

Comment: This is an I/O bound task. Multithreading or multiprocessing is unlikely to speed things up. Your code tends to open the file at position 0 and read 1 character at a time... I don't see how it jumps around the file. But as mentioned, it doesn't do much good.

Comment: I still want to try and see how threading can help. If I were to do it, how would I go about doing it? Do I just do threading.Thread(target=counter, args=(.....)) and it will work?

Comment: Is the file ASCII or utf-8 encoded? With an encoded file, its hard to "jump into the middle" because you may be in the middle of a multiple byte encoding, making this a difficult task.

Comment: Just a file of chars such as test.txt: sdsfsadfsfsrfiefuedhcfduhsodfas

Comment: Regarding you latest update: Can't you tell yourself if it works?

Answer (score 2):

There are three problems here.

Your program tries to read the same physical file in several threads at once.  That doesn't make sense and probably isn't feasible at the OS or hardware level.  What is feasible is first to read the entire file into several strings, in the main thread, and then operate on the strings (not the file) in multiple threads.

The second problem is that you return a value from the counter, but there is no place for the returned value to go.  There's no caller.  There's no such concept as "returning" a value from one thread to another.  Instead the thread must store the value somewhere, and code in the main thread can then access it.  A quick-and-dirty solution is to create a list and pass each thread an index.  When it's finished, it uses the index to stuff the result in the list.

The third problem is that you have to wait for the threads to finish.  Threads have a .join() function for this purpose.  Only after all the threads are done can you print a sum of all the counts.

This may be a useful learning exercise for you but it will surely be slower than doing the whole thing in one thread.  Threads are valuable when you have to wait for some event to occur, and you want to make progress on some other task in the meantime.  For simple number crunching there's no advantage to threads (there is for multiprocessing).

Answer (score 2):

Using multiple threads on a single file is not recommended, instead you can first save you content to a string and then split it into equal parts.

I would encourage you to use a helper class deriving from `threading.Thread`, so each Thread can have its own counter.

#### Code Example

```py
import threading


class Counter(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, text, char):
        super().__init__()
        self.counter = 0
        self.text = text
        self.char = char

    def run(self):
        for c in self.text:
            if c == self.char:
                self.counter += 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    char = "a"
    number_of_threads = 3
    threads = []
    counter = 0
    # Read your file before using threads to avoid IO errors
    file = open("my_file.txt", "r")
    text = file.read()
    # Split your text into parts, equal to the number of threads
    parts = [text[i:i + number_of_threads] for i in range(0, len(text), number_of_threads)]
    # Create and start a thread for each part
    for part in parts:
        thread = Counter(part, char)
        thread.start()
        threads.append(thread)
    # Join your threads and collect their numbers
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()
        counter += thread.counter

    print(counter)
```